# Spring deployment-level configuration

Tags: spring, jboss

When I wrote Java EE apps, I used JBoss Datasources to control which databases the deployment used. E.g. the dev versions would use a throwaway hibernate db, the ref and ops would use stable MySQL deployments. I also used MBeans to configure various other services and rules.

Now that I'm using Spring, I'd like the same functionality - deploy the same code, but with different configuration. Crucially, I'd also like Unit Tests to still run with stub services. My question is this - is there a way, in JBoss, to inject configuration with files which live outside of the WAR/EAR, and also include these files in test resources.

Comment: Spring can use the same JavaEE datasources as you used to use, why not keep on doing that? Similarly, Spring has good MBean support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add objects into the JNDI context by placing a file named xxx-service.xml into jboss's deploy directory. The app could then lookup the values via JNDI. In the example below the string "development" is added at java:/modes/deployment. To use JNDI in your unit tests use the [org.springframework.mock.jndi](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html) package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE server PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD MBean Service 4.0//EN"
          "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-service_4_0.dtd">
<server>
   <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
         name="c3po.naming:service=jndi-bindings">
      <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
         <jndi:bindings
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
            xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd"
            >

            <jndi:binding name="java:/modes/deployment">
               <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">development</jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>

            <jndi:binding name="java:/sites/abc">
               <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">dev.site.example.com</jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>

<!-- Examples:

            <jndi:binding name="urls/jboss-home">
               <jndi:value type="java.net.URL">http://www.jboss.org</jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>

            <jndi:binding name="hosts/localhost">
               <jndi:value editor="org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.InetAddressEditor">
                  127.0.0.1
               </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>

            <jndi:binding name="maps/testProps">
               <java:properties xmlns:java="urn:jboss:java-properties"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:java-properties resource:java-properties_1_0.xsd">
                  <java:property>
                     <java:key>key1</java:key>
                     <java:value>value1</java:value>
                  </java:property>
                  <java:property>
                     <java:key>key2</java:key>
                     <java:value>value2</java:value>
                  </java:property>
               </java:properties>               
            </jndi:binding>
-->

         </jndi:bindings>
      </attribute>
      <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
   </mbean>

</server>
```