# How to make a servlet to pre-compute the values when other servlet is accessed?

Tags: java, ajax, web-applications, servlets, implementation

I am working on a web application using java servlet and here is my scenario:

```
servlet1: Has the application's interface and main logic
servlet2: Suplies values to servlet1 on ajax request from servlet1
```

Totally there are 250 values that servlet1 can request. But calculating these values in servlet2 takes time(As it involves making GET request to other servers to get values). So calculating these values on request makes the client to wait for a long time.

So is there a way to make servlet2 to start pre-calculating the values when servlet1 is first called(so it can quickly send the values on request)?
Any help on how this can be implemented?

P.S. database or filesystem cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data that `servlet2` needs to precalculate is not dependant on `servlet1` input and needs to be calculated only once, either calculate it eagerly in [`ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) or in [`GenericServlet.init()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29). However it the computation takes some time, you'll better move it to some background thread to avoid long application startup time (these methods block deployment until they are finished).

Here is a simple example:

```
public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private Future<String> calculationResult;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        calculationResult = threadPool.submit(new PreComputingTask());
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String slowResponse = calculationResult.get();
        //...
    }
}

class PreComputingTask implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        //Call external systems, whatever...
        return "slow response";
    }
}
```

As you can see, when `servlet2` starts, it initiates pre computation task in a separate thread. Then in `doGet()` you retrieve the result, possibly waiting for it, if it hasn't finished yet.

If the pre-computation is dependant on input in `servlet1` (e.g. request parameters of `servlet1` need to be used when calling external system), it's much more challenging and interesting.

I see at least two options:

- start the `Future` task in `servlet1` and retrieve that future (hopefully already finished) in `servlet2`. You need to pass it somehow between the servlets, e.g. by placing it in `ServletContext`
- send a message to [jms](/questions/tagged/jms) queue from `servlet1`. Message listener will process the request, precomputing the results and putting the result in some temporary, unique queue. `servlet2` can then later receive message from that queue (you'll have to agree on some naming scheme somehow), or wait for it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I will try a filter to servlet1 that starts a async operation to calculate the values you need and then retrieve them in the logic of servlet2.

So basically you intercept the servlet1 request (with the filter) that triggers when servlet1 is first called and within the filter start precalculating values and them servlet2 retrieve the values on request from servlet1.

Comment: any reference on how to use the filters?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) is the oracle tutorial for jee 5

Answer (score 1):

Does servlet2 require some values from servlet1 to start calculating the values? If not, you could move the calculation code into a class separate from the two servlets. A ServletContextListener could then fire when the ServletContext is initialized, before any requests come in, and this could start the calculation. Once complete, it could store these results in the ServletContext

Servlet2 could then check if these results have been calculated (is it in the ServletContext?) and if so use that. Else it could calculate the individual value. Ideally, your separate class would know how to calculate all values (for the pre-calculation) or an individual value (for when the full list hasn't been completed yet).

Comment: any reference on how to call the class to start execution?

Comment: The first answer here loads some config and stores it in the context, so you could do something similar, but do the pre-calculation instead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153739/config-files-for-a-webapplication-load-once-and-store-where

Comment: You are particularly interested in the contextInitialized method (where you would fire off your pre-calculation), configuring the listener using web.xml, and the sample-code which shows you how to retrieve data from the context into one of your servlets