# jax-rs rest service calling properties files

Tags: java, web-services, rest, properties-file

## Context

I followed this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29567330/4245446) to create and load a properties file.

My backend code is splitted into 4 projects (Services,Business,DAO,Models)

**Services**

```
@Path("/users")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return UserBusiness.getUsers();
}
```

**Business**

```
public List<User> getUsers(){
    return _userDao.findAll();
}
```

**DAO**

```
public List<User> getUsers(){
    try{
        String query = "";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        //Query to DB here
    }catch(SQLException e){
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;
}
```

My properties file is stored in the `Services` project under the package `com.resources` and the class `ApplicationConfig` inside this project in the package `com.service` contains this

```
public static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "config.properties";
public static Properties properties = new Properties();

private Properties readProperties() {
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);
    if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return properties;
}
```

---

## The problem

My `Services` project contains the project `Models` as a dependency.

I need to retrieve a property value inside my `DAO` project (Maybe in other projects too later). I cannot add the project `Services` to my `DAO` project because it will add a cyclic dependency. Thus I cannot reach `ApplicationConfig.properties.getProperty("myprop")`.

How can I use the property file ? Should I let the `readProperties()` inside `ApplicationConfig` ? In which projects should I put the properties file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using a Singleton inside my `DAO` project. I will had 1 `config.properties` per project with the following class

```
public class PropertyHandler {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PropertyHandler.class.getName());

    private static PropertyHandler instance = null;

    private Properties props = null;

    private PropertyHandler() {
        try {
            props = new Properties();
            InputStream  in = PropertyHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            props.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error when loading DAO properties file\n***\n{0}", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static synchronized PropertyHandler getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PropertyHandler();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String getValue(String propKey) {
        return this.props.getProperty(propKey);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your DAO project should not be dependent for configuration on the same file as your Service project. You have 2 options:

- Load all your configurations once in your Service project into a class and it around. In this case you will end up with one big config file with configurations from ALL projects.
- reuse the config file loader code in a static method within a util class within a separate project. Every project can now have their own config files and depend on the util project for load the config file and reading it.

Comment: If I use the second approach meaning 1 config file per project. The config files would not be loaded at the start of the server but each time I read them ? Am I right ? Is their a better way to do it ?

Comment: Use the singleton pattern to store all properties at first read. That way all subsequent calls will not need extra file reads everytime.